# Couldn't able to add product in to shopping cart in opencart

Tags: php, shopping-cart, opencart

Am working with an opencart site. I've created a test site for my project. When I add a new product via test site then I got the message product successfully added to shopping cart. But the item is not appeared in the shopping cart. But all of these are working fine in the live site. Am using the same code and database for both live and test site..

Is there any configuration problem?

Comment: Double check the paths in ./config.php and admin/config.php. Sounds like you could've copied those.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine in config.php & admin/config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds to me like you've not assigned the store in the Links tab for the product. If you haven't you need to assign it to the store. If you have, my advice would be to clear any caches, such as `/system/cache/` and page cache folders if you use one